# ' << ' operator in verilog

Tags: operator-keyword, verilog

i have a verilog code in which there is a line as follows:

```
parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 8 ;
parameter RAM_DEPTH = 1 << ADDR_WIDTH;
```

here what will be stored in `RAM_DEPTH` and what does the `<<` operator do here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<<` is a binary shift, shifting 1 to the left 8 places.

```
4'b0001 << 1 => 4'b0010
```

`>>` is a binary right shift adding 0's to the MSB.
`>>>` is a signed shift which maintains the value of the MSB if the left input is signed.

```
4'sb1011 >>  1 => 0101
4'sb1011 >>> 1 => 1101
```

Three ways to indicate left operand is signed:

```
module shift;
  logic        [3:0] test1 = 4'b1000;
  logic signed [3:0] test2 = 4'b1000;

  initial begin
    $display("%b", $signed(test1) >>> 1 ); //Explicitly set as signed
    $display("%b", test2          >>> 1 ); //Declared as signed type
    $display("%b", 4'sb1000       >>> 1 ); //Signed constant
    $finish;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thank you .. :) and also thanks for sharing the concept of '>>>' operator.. :)

Comment: The >>> operator only preserves the MSB if the shifted operand is signed. If the shifted operand is unsigned, as in your example, the >>> operator inserts zeros just like the >> operator.

Comment: `$signed(test1) >>> 1` is not working for me. Xilinx ISE with ISim.

Comment: @Yvon It should work, unless bug in Xilinx ISE, you could post a question with a code example your trying. otherwise try it out on [eda playground](http://www.edaplayground.com).

Comment: @Morgan I pasted your second block of code into ISim, and it says `Syntax error near "signed".` and `logic is an unknown type`. It seems ISim does not recognize those keywords.

Comment: @Morgan Oh I changed `logic` to `reg` then all of the three works, giving `1100`.

Comment: @Yvon, those are System Verilog keywords, changing file extension to .sv often switches the compiler over.

Comment: @Yvon Signed has been part of verilog for some time, if that is not supported sounds like your stuck with verilog 95 syntax.

Comment: If it is register value do we need to assign to same variable

Comment: @ChandanChoudhury any variable can take the shifted value of another, just be careful with the word lengths.

Answer (score 6):

`1 << ADDR_WIDTH` means 1 will be shifted 8 bits to the left and will be assigned as the value for `RAM_DEPTH`.

In addition, `1 << ADDR_WIDTH` also means 2^ADDR_WIDTH.

Given `ADDR_WIDTH = 8`, then `2^8 = 256` and that will be the value for `RAM_DEPTH`

Answer (score 3):

`<<` is the left-shift operator, as it is in many other languages.

Here `RAM_DEPTH` will be `1` left-shifted by `8 bits`, which is equivalent to `2^8`, or `256`.